GPO Item interaction with Intune
We have a hybrid on-premise/Azure domain setup.  We are trying to push an inactivity timer of 5 minutes before screen lockout via Intune.  The policy worked for the first 11 computers I added, but others are locking out at 1 minute instead of the 5 that is specified.
So I looked in the on-premise DC, and I found a GPO item that I am not sure how is being applied.  Internally, it's called Disable Screen Auto-Lock and is set to apply to Authenticated Users.  I looked in the User Configuration > Policies > Administrative Templates > Control Panel > Personalization folder, but it shows it's not being applied to Screen Saver.  As a matter of fact, it shows Not Configured everywhere I look in the policy.
I don't understand if this GPO could be causing the wrong time lockout of if I should look elsewhere.
Have not tried any changes as I don't understand how the GPO might apply.
